# How to make proxy API requests to another server in angular-cli server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, server, angular-cli

**This is my proxy.config.ts file:**

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false
    }
}
```

**This is my package.json file:**

```json
"scripts": 
  {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

**This is my services file:**

```
 getrooms()
    {
      return this.http.get<roomlist[]>('/api')
    }
    addrooms(room:roomlist)
    {
      return this.http.post<roomlist[]>('/addrooms',room)
    }
    editroom(room:roomlist,aml:any)
    {
      return this.http.put<roomlist[]>(`/edit/${aml.roomno}`,room)
    }
    delete(id:number)
    {
      return this.http.delete<roomlist[]>(`/delete/${id}`)
    }
```

In this case the get method works properly. The put, post, delete method are not working, it shows cannot get localhost://4200/addrooms.   Could anyone fix it?